# Unable to get "Aggressive" gem on "The Sandgoose" rifle - is this a glitch?

Tags: fable-3

I've maxed out the other two gems (Adventurous and Popularity), and, when maxing out "Aggressive", the gem does not show up as enabled on my rifle.

Is this a glitch?

Comment: Update: I have an unofficial claim that the game prevents players from obtaining multiple weapon upgrades that do the same thing (Popularity and Aggressive both add +1 gold per enemy hit). Can anyone find a reference/substantiate the claim?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed have both Popularity and Aggressive on the Sandgoose (I have both, and gained them from 0-100% this morning).

Popularity is rather straight forward.  Doing a friend quest will advance it (there is an achievement for 20, this is just 10 more).  A faster way is to play a "good" character so everyone "loves" you and then giving them evil expressions till they become friends (no quest).  I can confirm this does work.

Aggressive is a little harder.  You have to get Guild Seals from Evil expressions.  Note, that doing an evil expression twice on the same person rarely garners a Guild Seal.  This took me between 50-70 people.  I also didn't always obtain the same number of Seals from every expression as flashing ones are worth more.

Comment: I've maxed both out, but only Aggressive shows and applies. I'm doing this on the PC - are you on the Xbox?

Comment: @Blue both show and I am on the 360